# Passing an inner class to gestureDetectorcompat as parameter

Tags: java, android-studio

Im trying to handle swipes on an app im building.
Found a way of doing this on youtube but it uses kotlin not java.

The method works with an inner class

```
class homepageGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
```

and in the super class i have

```
private GestureDetectorCompat detector;//needed to wire inner class to main activity
```

Below that, in the onCreate function im trying to assign the gestureDetector to the "detector"

```
detector=GestureDetectorCompat(this,homepageGestureListener());
```

this line gives the error "method call expected", it wont take `homepageGestureListener()` as a paramater.

How can i pass an inner class there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GestureDetectorCompat has 2 public constructors one that take a context and a listener and the other taking a context, a listener and a handler. In your case it's the first one. You need to pass an instance of your listener as the 2nd argument.
Someting like this:

```
//...

private GestureDetectorCompat mGestureDetector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        
        //...

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new LongPressListener()); // here passing LongPressListener()
    }

//..
}
```

Check on this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/GestureDetectorCompat#GestureDetectorCompat(android.content.Context,android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener)) on the official documentation to learn more.

EDIT:
Oh, your class extends `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`. Then in this case juste pass `this` as both arguments.

Like:

```
private GestureDetectorCompat detector
```

Then:

```
detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new homepageGestureListener());
```

I slightly edited the answer so you can pass an instance of your inner class instead.

Comment: `detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);` still gives an error. `'GestureDetectorCompat(android.content.Context, android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener)' in 'androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat' cannot be applied to '(com.example.testapp.MainActivity, com.example.testapp.MainActivity)' `

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you can pass the lintener with 'this' if you implemented GestureDetector.OnGestureListener or GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener, etc... What does happen when you simply do ``detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new homepageGestureListener());`` ?

Comment: I just made an edit, please try it

Comment: yess, that gets rid of the error. So i guess the classes you write are not "alive" in in compilation and you have to do "new" to create them in memory?

Comment: Yeah you need to instantiate that class first then pass it to the method

Comment: makes sense, thanks for the speedy help!